# check if an object is null

Tags: java

I have a linked list in which first node contains null object. means firstNode.data is equal to null, firstNode.nextPointer = null, firstNode.previousPointer = null.

And I want to check if firstNode is null or not.
So I tried-

```
if(list.firstNode == null){

            //do stuff          
        }
```

but this doesn't works?

I also tried equals too. Any suggestions?

I tried printing. And I got as-

{null} -- firstNode

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work" in greater detail.

Comment: It is not going inside that loop. That's what I mean.

Comment: So perhaps `list.firstNode` is not equal to `null`?

Comment: That comparison should work.  Use System.out.println() to print out the two values you're comparing.  You will likely find that what you're comparing to is not null.

Comment: Then it means that firstnode is not equal to null.

Comment: One point worth noting - there's no such thing as a null *object*; there's a null *reference*.

Comment: I tried printing. And I got as-

{null} -- firstNode

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your `firstNode` is *not* `null`, but its fields are. Try something like this:

```
if (list.firstNode.data == null) {
    //do stuff          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
if (list.firstNode.data == null) { /* Do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You checking for list.firstNode being null.  Do you mean to check for

```
list.firstNode.data==null
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question. You said:

```
 have a linked list in which first node contains null object. **means firstNode.data is equal to null**,
```

This means you should do the following instead:

```
if(list.firstNode.data == null){
     //do stuff          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your question is related to the processing of a doubly-linked list.
To check if empty use: `(list.firstNode.next == list.firstNode.previous)` this is `true` for an empty doubly linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all the fields of the node are null:

```
Node firstNode = list.firstNode;
if(firstNode.data == null &&
   firstNode.nextPointer == null &&
   firstNode.previousPointer == null) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Or to prevent code repetition, you can either create an instance method isNull() to do the test or create a NULL object and override the equals method in your Node class to check if a node is equal to the null node as you described.

```
class Node<E> {
    //The null node, assuming your constructor takes all three values.
    public static final Node NULL = new Node(null, null, null);

    //Fields here with constructors etc.

    @Override
    public void equals(Object obj) {
        if(!obj instanceof Node) return false;
        Node<?> node = (Node<?>)obj;
        if(node.data.equals(this.data) &&
           node.nextPointer == this.nextPointer &&
           node.previousPointer == this.previousPointer) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then when you want to check if a node is null you can do:

```
if(list.firstNode.equals(Node.NULL)) {
    //Do stuff
}
```