# if statment not working

Tags: android, if-statement, uri

I'm trying to do a test:

1. if `String==null` or if `String.equals(null)`.
2. then upload image that i get from gallery.
3. else then upload image from mipmap.

But it's not working,I tied also `String!=uriBook` and i checked uriBook it return null when i don't select image from gallery.

**Update source:**

I'm using Bundle because imagePath is in my first fragment and i'm doing the upload in fragment 2

fragment 1:

```
if(filePath!=null){bundle.putString("uRI", filePath.toString());}
```

Frgment 2:

uriBook=String.valueOf(bundle.getString("uRI"));

```
private void uploadFile() {

if(uriBook == null )  {

    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
            "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            + '/' + getResources().getResourceTypeName(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
    progressDialog.show();

    StorageReference storageRefDef = storageDef.getReference();
    getRiversRefDef = storageRefDef.child("images/" + nomstaockageImage);
    getRiversRefDef.putFile(imageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    pathStoageInFirebase = getRiversRefDef.getPath();
                    Log.e(TAG, "path image" + pathStoageInFirebase);
                    createBook(titreBook, descBook, prixBook, regionBook, viileBook, currentDateandTime, catBook, typeBook, pathStoageInFirebase);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccueilActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            });}
else {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
    progressDialog.show();

    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+nomstaockageImage);

    riversRef.putFile(Uri.parse(uriBook))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    pathStoageInFirebase=  riversRef.getPath();
                    Log.e(TAG, "path image"+pathStoageInFirebase);
                    createBook(titreBook, descBook, prixBook, regionBook, viileBook, currentDateandTime, catBook, typeBook, pathStoageInFirebase);

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccueilActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            });
} }
```

Exception err at

```
riversRef.putFile(Uri.parse(uriBook))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){}

No content provider: null
                                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: null
                                                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:710)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:614)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:449)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.mydreambook.AddBookFinalFragment.uploadFile(AddBookFinalFragment.java:283)
                                                                     at com.mydreambook.AddBookFinalFragment.access$000(AddBookFinalFragment.java:39)
                                                                     at com.mydreambook.AddBookFinalFragment$2.onClick(AddBookFinalFragment.java:174)
```

If uriBook is null why source between if statement not executed ?

**Update with Image debuger **

[image]

Comment: your question is unclear. Also note that any non-null object `equals(null)` returns `false`

Comment: Not exactly sure what the problem is?

Comment: try `uriBook.equals==null` instead of `uriBook.equals(null)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if an object is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352559/check-if-an-object-is-null)

Comment: Several things to note:
Why are you doing `String uriBook=String.valueOf(bundle.getString("uRI"))`?
getString() will actually return a String, and if it returns null valueOf will throw a null pointer exception.

Comment: @JuanMartinez I'm using Bundle to stock filePath from frag1 to frag2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your code:

```
if(uriBook.equals(null))
```

will get you `nullPointerException` in some point, because if your `uriBook` will be null, then it tries to call metohd (equal) from a null object. Change it to.

```
if(uriBook == null)
```

If problem still exists, tell us what's wrong, what is error message.

==Update

[image]

Yeah, you set string with value "null" to your `uriBook` variable. Like on picture, `n1` is a string with value "null" and `n2` is actually `null`

To set null to variable you have to set:

```
uriBook = null;
uriBook = "null"; //gives you a string with value "null"
```

To check if variable has "null" value you have to check it like this:

```
if (uriBook.equals("null")){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: trace says that there is no file `Uri.parse(uriBook)`  check it out, remember that path must contain extension of file like `.jpg` or `.png` etc.

Comment: `Uri.parse(uriBook)` is on else statement , I'm asking why  source else statement executed ? normally it'is the if statement mut be executed.I'm sure that my variable uriBook=null

Comment: Well it's not null ;) You can debug it, but I'm sure that it's not null. Before if execution you can set uriBook to null `uriBook == null;` and then it will execute your `if` and not `else`

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable is null:

```
if(uriBook == null) /*is null*/
```

You only can call Object's methods like 'equals()' if you have an object instance. If your variable 'uriBook' is null, you don't have any instance there, and will throw a NullPointerException.

Also, this kind of things are really easy to solve if you debug your code. Put a breakpoint in the 'if' line, and inspect the variable content. You may be understanding the situation wrong, like your variable may not be null, but their attributes do.

Comment: I put a beakpont in the if line , my variable uriBook=null

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (yourString == null){

}
```

and if you sure that can't be nullPointerException try

```
if (yourString.isEmpty()){

}
```